# Indicating object has any number of key:string properties aside from the known ones

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create a type that has some known properties:

```
{
  name: string;
  count: number;
}
```

But could also have any other "unknown" properties that aren't included in the first type.

My initial instinct was to do:

```
{
  name: string;
  count: number;
} & { [key: string]: any }
```

But this causes even the known `name` and `count` properties to be recognised as `any`.

Any idea how I can get this to work? I can't control the shape of the object I'm receiving.

Comment: What exactly is wrong about your approach? It works fine for what you described it.

Comment: @Behemoth Types on both `name` and `count` are set to `any` as soon as I add `& { [key: string]: any }`. I don't think it works as intended.

Comment: Can't reproduce. Works perfectly fine for me. Both `name` and `count` keep their value types. Check out this [TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgdgS2AghgGygXigbwFBRRwoC2EAXFAM7ABOCcA5gNwFQDGA9gK5zCVxuJAEYRarAL6s8oSFACiAD2AQ4AEwhqsuNsTKUa9Jq0Jde-IkNHi8EqADJcUANoBrCCAN0GjALqUUOBAoKTw8LjgaKBUaSiUVdU1tfEI9CigAIjSMgBo2Mz5KADYSvMIqTjIAeWAACzEABVpOSFpQSgzOADMAQSCAFXAIXNtWIA)

Comment: That's strange, I must be doing something wrong somewhere else! Thank you for the TS playground :D